# inet_aton converts 010.000.000.001 wrong?

Tags: c, sockets, inet-aton

I am having problem with `inet_aton` to convert a network address. The code below works fine to convert the address `10.0.0.1`

```
char *x1;
struct sockaddr_in si_other;
inet_aton("10.0.0.1", &si_other.sin_addr);
printf("si_other.sin_addr =%lu\n",si_other.sin_addr);
x1 = inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr);
printf("x1=%s\n",x1);
```

It outputs:

```
si_other.sin_addr =16777226
x1=10.0.0.01
```

No problem so far. However, the function works weird when `010.000.000.001` is passed

```
char *x2;
struct sockaddr_in si_other2;
inet_aton("010.000.000.001", &si_other2.sin_addr);
printf("si_other2.sin_addr =%lu\n",si_other2.sin_addr);
x2 = inet_ntoa(si_other2.sin_addr);
printf("x2=%s\n",x2);
```

outputs:

```
si_other.sin_addr2 =16777224
x2=8.0.0.01
```

The function works fine when `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.000.001` are passed.

Can anyone explain me what is the problem and how I can fix the problem? (note: I need to pass the IP address as `010.000.000.001` in my code)

Comment: If you can't normalize your dotted-decimal addresses to the standard variable-width notation, you'll have to write your own function approximately equivalent to `inet_aton` that handles non-standard fixed width, leading-zero padded IPv4 addresses.  Have fun!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The leading 0 is being [interpreted as indicating the number is octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation#Caveat). 010 (oct) == 8 (dec). You need to modify the input to `inet_aton` to avoid this, or convert it yourself in a different way.

```
const char *str = "010.000.000.001";
inet_aton(str[0] == '0' ? str+1:str, &si_other.sin_addr);
```

Is the simplest solution, but it would be better to fix whatever (`snprintf`?) produces the string in the first place to avoid the confusion.

(As it stands that solution won't work with a number of edge cases still, including "001.0.0.1", "0xF.0.0.1", "1" and many more valid IPv4 addressees).

You can trivially "normalise" your input using `sscanf`, even if you can't control how it gets generated in the first place (although that really ought to be a bug whever it came from in my view):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  const char *str="010.020.030.040";
  int parts[4];
  sscanf(str, "%d.%d.%d.%d", parts+0, parts+1, parts+2, parts+3);
  char *out = NULL;
  asprintf(&out, "%d.%d.%d.%d", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
  printf("%s\n", out);
  free(out);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would that yield on `010.020.030.040`?  Clearly, the first field would be `10` (decimal), but what about the others?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler still wouldn't fix that case.

Comment: The correct solution would be to left-trim the 0's from all octets. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Sven also said that `090` and `070` are also producing `8`, but `090` octal is not valid, and `070` octal is `56` decimal.

Comment: @jweyrich: in this particular case, yes trim the leading zeros.  But what if you actually want to convert a string with octals in it? The zeros are then needed.

Comment: it was my fault '090' '070' outputs different values.I forgot to clean the project before run the code again. Thank you for the explanation and solution

Comment: @sven - I added a possibly better solution

Comment: I can't give you an extra +1, more's the pity.  Short of packaging it as a function, there's not a lot more you can do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you raised a very valid point. As the question stands, showing IPs that aren't base-8 but still and erroneously have leading zeroes, such as `192.168.000.001`, the only solution is to trim (or normalize) it. In the general scenario, one would not need to do any extra processing. The conversion done by `inet_aton` should work flawlessly for decimal, octal, and hexa.

Comment: Yet, I don't understand why **[this](http://ideone.com/vXJ703)** outputs `inet_aton: Success` to stderr. It should output something like `inet_aton: Undefined error: 0`. It seems that errno isn't being set properly. Bug? Sorry for the extended discussion here. I should be using chat I guess.